# Can I saute in one pan and bake in another?

Tags: chicken, pan, sauteing

Usually I saute my chicken then put the pan in the oven to finish cooking. But I need to make more than my one oven safe pan will hold. Can I saute in a few pans and then transfer all the chicken into a baking pan to finish cooking? Would I need to add oil to the baking pan and/or let it preheat in the oven?

Comment: Are you putting the sauteed chicken on cookie sheets, or a roasting pan?

Comment: A cookie sheet or a cake pan. I'm using my only roasting pan for veggies.

Comment: Only use the cookie sheet if it has a "lip" or sides on it, otherwise you risk having juice spilling onto the floor of your oven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly can. To make cleaning up easier I would line it with parchment paper rather than add oil, although a little bit of oil would work too. There shouldn't be any reason to preheat the baking pan before putting it in the oven.